# How to make a list/array of turtles-on patch-here?

Tags: netlogo

i have no experience on netlogo, so i am asking if someone know how to set the greatest energy of a turtle on patch-here. If i have on a patch an agent y and 3, 2 or 4 x´s , i want to agent y stay with the biggest energy of those 3,i know i have to do a loop but  how do I loop not knowing how many x-type agents are in this patch?

```
breed [ y ys]
breed [ x ys]
x-own[ energy]
y-own [ energy ]

    to move-y
    ask y[
      if count x-on patch-here > 2
      [
       set breed x
       ;anyone can help ?
       let energy one-of x-on patch-here ; this is wrong because i dont want a random 
      ]
    ]
    end
```

hope you can help me =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably should not be thinking in terms of loops. NetLogo has lots of primitives that operate on agentsets (like `ask` and `of`) and on lists (like `foreach` and `map`) but you almost never have to write an explicit loop with an index that you increment.

Another remark about your code: you have inverted the plural and the singular name when declaring your breeds. The plural has to come first, so it should be `breed [ xs x ]` instead of `breed [ x xs ]`.

Now, regarding your specific problem: you don't need `patch-here`, since NetLogo also provides a [`<breeds>-here`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here) primitive that does what you need a bit more directly.

As for getting the maximum energy of all the `xs` on the path, you can simply use the [`max`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#max) primitive:

```
breed [ xs x ]
breed [ ys y ]
xs-own [ energy]
ys-own [ energy ]

to move-y
  ask ys [
    if count xs-here > 2 [
      set energy max [ energy ] of xs-here
      set breed xs
    ]
  ]
end
```

Note that results might differ depending on whether you change to breed of the current `y` to `xs` before or after setting the `energy`. I'll let you try to figure out why.